# scrolling through list view

Tags: android

In my app I'm using base adapter to display continents on list view.I want to display 2 text views and 1 image view on list.The image view is displayed on flag condition.For the 1 st time it displays everything properly.But if i scroll through my list the unexpected behavior us there.The image view is displayed on the row for which flag is false.Below is my code...
    Please help me!!!!

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    { 
        private Context context;
        Views viewsList;
        private ArrayList<Views> selectedItems = new ArrayList<Views>();

        public MyAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Views> list) {
            super();
            this.context=c;

            this.selectedItems=list;
        }


        public int getCount() {

            return selectedItems.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return selectedItems.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            viewsList=selectedItems.get(position);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            View v=convertView; 
            ImageView tipImageView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView bTitle,textVies,likeView;
            if (v == null) {

                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tips_viwes_and_like_gui, null);

                bTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textname);
                bTitle.setText(viewsList.getName());

                if(viewsList.getContaisImage().contains("1"))
                {
                    tipImageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.setImageId);
                    tipImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tip_image);
                }
                else if(viewsList.getContaisImage().contains("0"))
                {
                    tipImageView=null;
                }

                 textVies = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviews);
                textVies.setText("Views :"+viewsList.getViewsId());

                likeView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textLike);
                likeView.setText("Like :"+viewsList.getLike());
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Everything is in `if(v==null)`. Keep the first line which is `v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tips_viwes_and_like_gui, null);` and remove everything put it out of the **if statement**

Comment: @Sherif..thanks for ur responce....but no luck....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common problem you will have to write the else part of this line
try this way

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            viewsList=selectedItems.get(position);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            View v=converView; 
            ImageView tipImageView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView bTitle,textVies,likeView;

            if (v == null) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tips_viwes_and_like_gui, null);    

                bTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textname);
                textVies = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviews);
                likeView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textLike);
                tipImageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.setImageId);
            }

            bTitle.setText(viewsList.getName());
            likeView.setText("Like :"+viewsList.getLike());
            textVies.setText("Views :"+viewsList.getViewsId());
            tipImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tip_image);

            if(viewsList.getContaisImage().contains("0")){
               tipImageView.setVisibile(ImageView.GONE);
            }else{
               tipImageView.setVisibile(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }

            return v;
        }
```